# SQL Server 2017 chinese characters and database collation

Tags: sql-server, collation

Starting with a brand new database, I would like to know what is the best option for storing multi language characters like English, Brazilian, French and Chinese.
I was thinking about using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` as the database collation and `NVARCHAR` type for columns.

Could someone give some more advise ?

Comment: `nvarchar` or `nchar` type will  take care of the characters since those will be Unicode. The collation determines the rules for linguistic sorting and comparison so there will be compromises when you store a mix of Latin and non-Latin languages using a single collation.

Comment: Yes, I agree and quite understand that for pure sql script. But my final goal is using C# and more precisely Entity Framework Core. So will it be compliant with c# ?

Comment: Use a Windows collation (e.g. `Latin1_General_CI_AS`) instead of a SQL collation if you want the same sorting rules in SQL as the app code.

Comment: I finally used 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'.